# file upload windows form c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

How to copy a file from one location to the other location using windows form in C#.? Thanks. I am creating a function to select a file and then copy it to some other folder. For selecting a file I use `OpenFileDialog` but I don't know how to copy it.

Comment: Upload to what? A network share? An FTP server? HTTP? Other?

Comment: upload to own local pc.

Comment: Thanks @rezomegreldize, I can copy it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So to move the file to another folder you might do something like this:

```
File.Copy(openFileDialog.FileName,
    Path.Combine(targetPath, Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog.FileName))
```

where `targetPath` is the UNC path to the target location.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean exactly by upload. Here I assumed that you want to copy one file from one source location to the other location.

```
   string sourceDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"somewhere in your hard");
   string destinationDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"somewhere else in your hard");
   File.Copy(sourceDir, destinationDir);
```

Comment: yeah it is more like copying to other folder. Thanks for your help

Comment: So this is useful for you :)